# Establish Spring Bean that is dependent on application location

Tags: java, spring-mvc, azure-cloud-services

I'm working on a web MVC implementation of Spring. I establish a Bean during configuration that represents a database connection. The connection Bean is initialized with a boolean representing whether this is the test or live environment, which controls which respective database to connect to. Therefore, my config contains something like:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionManager connectionManager() throws Exception{
    boolean isLive = true; /* This should be variable based on my environment */
    return new ConnectionManager (isLive);
}
```

I am deploying this web app to microsoft azure as a cloud service using the [Azure Toolkit for Eclipse](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation/). I have two separate cloud apps, representing the respective test & live environment.

**My Problem** is that I can't think of anyway to programatically determine whether it is the live environment. Ideally I would be able to extract the base URI from a request and use that to determine the it, but that information isn't available at the time of config.

Maybe my approach is just all wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it is generally a bad idea to make your beans aware of your environment. That being said, are the beans exactly the same for test/live but just need different connection properties (key/val pairs?)

Comment: Yes the beans are exactly the same with the exception of the connection properties.

Comment: your beans shouldn't be aware of your environment. This is bad design. I recommend using property injection. See new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bean shouldn't be aware of your environment. This is bad design. If the beans use the exact same logic you should be injecting the connection properties via xxx.properties file on your classpath (src/main/resources) and this file should have different values in your code branches for each environment. So on your repository you would have a 'test' branch and a 'live' branch where both a connection.properties are in the same path src/main/resource but they have different key/value pairs. This decouples your configuration from your actual code.

So something like this (from Spring documentation)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new DriverManagerDataSource(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

and a jdbc.properties file in src/main/resources

```
#contents of jdbc.properties ( on 'test' branch )
jdbc.url=someHost.com/db
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=secret

#contents of jdbc.properties ( on 'live' branch )
jdbc.url=someHost.com/db_prod
jdbc.username=asdasdasda
jdbc.password=as3432543$$#@%@#
```

There are several ways to manage properties in spring... I have provided links below demonstrating how to do this:

http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring

http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/UsingPropertySourceAndEnvironment.html

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-injecting-property-values-into-configuration-beans/

Comment: I can't say I love the idea of continuously merging test and live repositories, but this is indeed the best approach. It didn't occur to me that a property file could be intentionally different in different repo branches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a solution.. Its not very elegant, but it works.

I make my ConnectionManager class available to controllers with:

```
@Autowired
protected ConnectionManager manager;
```

My solution was to access the connection manager through a method rather than directly. The method evaluates the the request and decides whether to the manager's environment needs to be updated. I.e:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionManager manager;

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest context;

/*
 * Return an updated manager instance
 */
protected ConnectionManager getConnectionManager(){
    /*
    ... Logic that evaluates the HttpServletRequest 
    ... and changes the ConnectionManager accordingly.
    */
    return manager;
}
```

This logic lies in an abstract controller class that all my controllers extend. This makes it easy for all the controllers to access an updated version of the manager.

Obviously this isn't perfect, and adds additional overhead to any request that needs access to the connection manager, but I haven't found any alternatives.